# admin/reports/updates page not found

Tags: 8

On a Drupal 8 project, the *admin/reports/updates* is not accessible. It just returns a 404 error without any issue.

Comment: Did you enable the corresponding module?

Comment: Thanks, yes it was the issue, I thought it is something in core.

Answer (score 1):

The [Update Manager](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/update-manager) module is a Drupal core module, but [it's not installed from the Standard profile](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21profiles%21standard%21standard.info.yml/8.9.x), which is the default installation profile used from Drupal.
Before installing the *Update Manager* module, none of [its routes](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21update%21update.routing.yml/8.9.x) is available. You won't get any issue, except a 404 error when you try to access them.